# Android: Home launcher activity is recreated into new task only the first time when pressing HOME

Tags: android, android-intent, android-launcher, android-homebutton, android-task

I want to prevent user from leaving my app. I am trying to achieve this through home launcher activity/application and I don't understand android's behaviour. Pressing HOME first time always creates new activity **in new task** instead of moving the existing one to the foreground. When pressing HOME second time etc, nothing happens. See example:

I have a Login activity (A) and Settings activity (B). B is opened from A. A is set to be a launcher (LAUNCHER, DEFAULT, HOME categories).

1. A opens B

   - task T1: A -> B
2. HOME
3. **another A is created into a new task (why?):**

   - T1: A -> B
   - T2: A
4. A opens B (task T2)
5. - T1: A -> B
   - T2: A -> B
6. HOME
7. **nothing happens, why?**

I get the same behaviour when A's *launchMode* is either *singleTop*, *singleTask* or *standard*. With *singleInstance* there is only one A, but the B gets alone in T1 and I don't want that.

**Why there is always a new task created?** All intents flags have **always** the *FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK* flag set. Why does android do that?

Is it the same behaviour as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283079/re-launch-of-activity-on-home-button-but-only-the-first-time) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341600/how-to-prevent-multiple-instances-of-an-activity-when-it-is-launched-with-differ)? I can't use that solution because android creates a new task so A will always be the root. (or how can I check that this is a second instance?)

I can't use *singleInstance* as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548947/how-to-prevent-custom-home-launcher-app-restart-activity), because I don't want B to be alone (if A is visible, it is also the only activity and task (login purposes)). I tried to remove all other tasks through ActivityManager but `getAppTasks()` is for SDK >= 21, my min is 16.

I can't even use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337217/how-to-return-to-the-latest-launched-activity-when-re-launching-application-afte) solution because I never get intent with FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT flag. There is always FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED flag.

I've tried a lot of combinations with *launchMode, clearTaskOnLaunch, noHistory, ...* but nothing successful - always new task.

Any idea how to solve this? Running on Lollipop. Thank you.

Comment: Having the exact same problem. Has there been any solution to this issue?